# Xamarin forms background stay white

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, background

I tried to change background in xamarin.Forms to gray for android, but it still stays white in my phone. Only in Simulator it is gray.
I directly set backgroundcolor Attribute in page xaml item and also in First stackpanel.

Comment: instead of *describing* your code, please post the **actual** code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you check the dark mode or light mode when you run your project on the device? In addition, did you try to test it on the different device?